# Java reading in a string and converting numbers in strings into Integers types

Tags: java

I am trying to take numbers from a users string (if it has numbers) and convert those numbers to their numerical value.  I have the following code which takes in user input.

Ex:  `java Convert "55s"` will just output the number 55, which i will store for later usage

```
{
      char Element = 0;
      double Sum = 0;
      boolean Check = false;

        for(String s: args)  // taking in user input for command line 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++)
            {
              Check = true;
              Element = s.charAt(i);          // converting the string into chars
              Sum = convert_to_numb (Element, Check);
              Check = false;
            }
        }
```

The input is a string in which i separate into chars and send it to my conversion functions. The idea i have follows

```
 public static double convert_to_numb (char elem, boolean check)  //trying to convert chars to numbers
  {
      char iter = elem;
      double number = 0;
      int count = 0;

        while (check == true)
        {
             number  =  number +  (iter - 48) * Math.pow(10,count);
             System.out.println(iter);
             count ++;
        }

     return number; 
  }
```

Here I am feeding in the chars to see if they're numbers and convert the actual numbers into their integer value. To try to clarify i would like to perform the following task given an example input of "55" covert it to 5*10^1 + 5*10^0 = 55. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: one question, if the string is `"foo55bar66baz77"`what would you store?

Comment: What i am trying to do is essentially create a small calculator, and to answer your question ill have an idea of what the equation is, since this is a HW assignment, so ill store 55, 66, 77 into separate variables in the main

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I might know what you're trying to accomplish, though as others have mentioned it is a little unclear.

To address the code you just posted, I don't think it'll behave the way you expect. For starters, the Boolean variable 'Check' accomplishes nothing at the moment.  convert_to_numb is only called while Check is true, so it's redundant.

Additionally, the sum isn't being stored anywhere as you loop through the string. Every time you obtain a sum, it overwrites the previous one.

Your convert_to_numb method is even more troubling; it contains an infinite loop.  Since Check is always set to 'true', you essentially have a while(true) loop that will never end.

I'm going to assume that your objective here is to parse whichever Strings are input into the program looking for groups of consecutive digits.  Then you want to store these groups of digits as integers, perhaps in an array if you find multiple.

Something like this might do the trick.

```java
{
    ArrayList<Integer> discovered = new ArrayList<Integer>();        

    for (String s : args) {

        // contains previous consecutive digits (if any)
        ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character c = s.charAt(i);

            // add digit to digit array
            if (c.isDigit()) {
                digits.add(c.getNumericValue())
            }

            // not a digit, so we clear the digit array
            else {

                // combine the array to form an integer
                if (! digits.isEmpty()) {
                    int sum = 0;

                    int counter = 0;
                    for (Integer i : digits) {
                        sum += i * Math.pow(10, counter);
                        counter++;
                    }

                    discovered.add(sum);
                    digits.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of ArrayLists and the Integer and Character wrapper classes. These all provide functionality that helps deal with edge-cases. For example, I'm not sure that `(iter - 48)` part would have worked in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "55s";
    String[] piece = string.split("[\\D]+");
    for (int j = 0; j < piece.length; j++) {
        if(piece[j].trim().length() > 0) {
            System.out.println(piece[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

It will split your initial string, the rest you should do yourself.